# Selecting specific counties using selectlayerbyattribute in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I have a shapefile for counties containing many fields, among which `Pop_Descrp` is one.

I need to select the counties with `Highly Increased` attribute under the field and export it.

I am not able to make correct expression for query. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace=r"Z:\Ash Tree Project\Shapefiles_Arkansas"
env.OverwriteOutput=True

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("County_AR.shp","County_layer")    
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("County_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", "[Pop_Descrp]='Highly Increased'" )    
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("County_layer", "HighPopR_counties.shp")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What happens when you run your code?  Does it give an error or do anything at all?  Please [edit] your question to include this extra info

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) to ensure fields are correctly specified in your selection query:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Z:\Ash Tree Project\Shapefiles_Arkansas"
arcpy.env.OverwriteOutput = True

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("County_AR.shp", "County_layer")

query = "{0} = 'Highly Increased'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("County_layer", 'Pop_Descrp'))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("County_layer", "NEW_SELECTION", query)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("County_layer", "HighPopR.shp")
```

Also I think Shapefiles can't have long filenames, so I have shorted the output shapefile name in your `arcpy.CopyFeatures()`

Comment: To compliment @Midavalo's answer `query` would evaluate as `""""Pop_Descrp" = 'Highly Increased'"""`, so note that the field delimiters are double quotes not square brackets. If you find a tool not working try running it in ArcMap then go to results and copy snippet and that will give you the correct syntax.

Comment: @Midavalo. Thanks for suggesting. I tried it and there is no error on the process. "HighPopR.shp" is created but when I open the shapefile, its empty; there are no any polygons of counties queried. I would appreciate even more if you could suggest me on this.

Comment: @Bee_Show Can you confirm that `Highly Increased` is definitely a valid value in the `Pop_Descrp` field?

Comment: @Midavalo. Yes, it is valid value under Pop_Descrp. Pop_Descrp has four types of values: Highly Increased, Moderately Increased, Nominally Increased, and Decreased. When I perform the query form select by attributes in ArcGIS, it woks well.